# Where does exactly Vue keep-alive cache the component?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js

I'm on Nuxtjs 2.13 ssr mode. As I read the Docs on Vuejs and Nuxtjs, it just mentions that with keep-alive, the component will be cached in memory, but which one?? In server RAM memory or Client RAM memory?? it's really important for me because I have a device (mobile) version of my webapp and must be cautious of RAM usage.

Comment: Obviously in the client's memory. Vue is a frontend framework which runs on your client not on the server.

Comment: @dhruwlalan , I'm on Nuxt ssr. same??